# Last substitution to conclude

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Let A be definite symmetric matrix. Let X a random variable with value in $\mathbb R^n$.
We define the the Mahalanobis distance by : $d_{s}(\mu_1,\mu_0)^2 = (\mu_1-\mu_0)^{T}A^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)),$ with $\mu_{1},\mu_0 \in \mathbb R^n$. Let $\mu_0,\mu_1 \in \mathbb R^n$. We know that

$$\mathbb P((\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})^{T}A^{-1}(X-\frac{(\mu_{1}+\mu_{0})}{2})>0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n \det(A)}}\int \limits_{\mathbb  R^n  }e^{(-\frac{1}2 (x-\mu_{0})^{T}A^{-1}(x-\mu_{0})} 1_{ (\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})^{T}A^{-1}(x-\frac{(\mu_{1}+\mu_{0})}{2})>0 }dx$$

And I have to show that

$$\mathbb P((\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})^{T}A^{-1}(X-\frac{(\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})}{2})>0)=\Phi(-\frac{d_{s}(\mu_1,\mu_0)^2}{2})$$where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard Gaussian. So I understand that : $$\Phi(-\frac{d_{s}(\mu_1,\mu_0)^2}{2})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \limits_{[-\infty,-\frac{d_{s}(\mu_1,\mu_0)^2}{2}[}{e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}}dt$$

My try :

with the substitution $u=x-\mu_{0}$ :

$$\mathbb P((\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})^{T}A^{-1}(X-\frac{(\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})}{2})>0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n \det(A)}}\int \limits_{\mathbb  R^n}e^{(-\frac{u^{T}A^{-1}u}2 )}1_{-(\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})^{T}A^{-1}u<-\frac{d_{s}(\mu_1,\mu_0)^2}{2} }du$$

With the spectral theorem, we have :

$A^{-1}=Q^{T}DQ $ where $Q$ is orthogonal and  $D$ a  diagonal matrix

(With $R=\sqrt{D}$ (Because A is Definite symmetric matrix, So $A^{-1}=Q^{T}RRQ$)

$$\mathbb P((\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})^{T}A^{-1}(X-\frac{(\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})}{2})>0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n \det(A)}}\int \limits_{\mathbb  R^n}e^{(-\frac{(RQu)^{T}RQu}2 )}1_{-(\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})^{T}A^{-1}u<-\frac{d_{s}(\mu_1,\mu_0)^2}{2} }du$$

(With substitution $z=RQu$ we get ($det(Q)=1$) $dz=det(Q)det(R)du=det(\sqrt{D})du=\sqrt{det(A^{-1})}du=\frac{du}{\sqrt{det(A)}}$, thus $du=\sqrt{det(A)}dz$  and $(QR)^{-1}z=u$)

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{n}}}\int \limits_{\mathbb  R^n  }e^{(-\frac{z^{T}z}2 )} 1_{-(\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})^{T}A^{-1}((QR)^{-1}z)<-\frac{d_{s}(\mu_1,\mu_0)^2}{2}}dz$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{n}}}\int \limits_{\mathbb  R^n }e^{(-\frac{z^{T}z}2 )} 1_{-(\mu_{1}-\mu_{0})^{T}(Q^{T}R)z<-\frac{d_{s}(\mu_1,\mu_0)^2}{2}}dz$$

My ideas : use the fact that $z^{T}z=||z||^{2}=\mathbb \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}^{2}$, and try to see my integral as the multiplication of n integrals, which i think is the last step to conclude.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the distribution of $X$? A Gaussian with mean $\mu_0$ and covariance matrix $A$?

Comment: The law of X is defined on this post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933641/error-minimization-for-machine-learning

Comment: Should i add that information here ? won't it make the post too long and prevent poeple to read it ? @sudeep5221

Comment: Maybe add a small description or reference? Because without specifying the distribution of $X$, the problem description is incomplete and people won't be able to solve it anyway. Also, it seems from the first integral that you have assume $X$ to be a Gaussian with mean $\mu_0$ and covariance $A$? If not, can you please explain how you got the first integral?